# How to overlay part of an image over a video?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner learning to code, I am trying to clone a Netflix login page.

There is a section where I have to play a video inside a computer image. As I tried, I was able to fit the video in the computer. But when I even tried to use z-index to make some part of image cover over video, it's not working as shown in the expected result. Please let me know if I am missing something.

**Image link:** https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/device-pile-in.png

**Video link:** https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/video-devices-in.m4v

**Expected is**: https://i.imgur.com/Egv9qyZ.mp4

**My output is**: https://i.imgur.com/oUjUXRb.gifv

**HTML**

```
 <div class="section-tv-container">
      <section class="section-tv">
        <div class="tv-feature-text">
          <h1>Watch everwhere.</h1>
          <h2>
            Stream unlimited movies and TV shows on your phone, tablet, laptop,
            and TV.
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tv-container2">
          <div id="tv_container">
            <video
              class="tv-video2"
              autoplay=""
              playsinline=""
              muted=""
              loop=""
              width="300"
              height="240"
            >
              <source
                src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/video-devices-in.m4v"
                type="video/mp4"
              />
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section-tv-container {
  border-top: 8px solid #222;
  height: 48.2rem;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}


.section-tv {
  height: 32.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.tv-feature-text h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  width: 41.4rem;
}

.tv-feature-text h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  width: 51.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}


.tv-container2 {
  position: relative;
}

#tv_container {
  background: url("https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/device-pile-in.png");
  width: 400px; /* Adjust TV image width */
  height: 35.8rem; /* Adjust TV image height */
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* z-index: 100; */
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.tv-video2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 120px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it,

NOTE: this code is for explanation purpose only ( you cant just copy/paste and expect to get everything in its place) understand the code then try to re-implement it.

If got stuck, don't hesitate to ask, good luck

```css
#tv_container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}

.monitor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/device-pile-in.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.tv-video2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 109px;
  width: 378px;
  height: 291px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="tv_container">
      <div class="monitor"></div>
      <video
        class="tv-video2"
        autoplay=""
        playsinline=""
        muted=""
        loop=""
        width="300"
        height="240"
      >
        <source
          src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/video-devices-in.m4v"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, but thing is my background color is black, which overrides the video. Not sure why. If I remove the background color, this works perfectly.

Comment: thats because the z-index property, I updated the code. check it now

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is that the Video is a Child-Element of the Tv-Image. So if you change the z-index of the TV-Image you also change the z-index of the video itself. What you need to do is put the video in a seperate div and position it on the position you want to have and set the Z-Index. Important is that the Image-background is no parent-element of the Video.
Something like this:

```
   <div class="tv-container2">
      <div id="tv_container">
      </div>
      <div class="tv-video2">
        <video
          autoplay=""
          playsinline=""
          muted=""
          loop=""
          width="300"
          height="240"
        >
          <source
            src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/video-devices-in.m4v"
            type="video/mp4"
          />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and then Set the z-index for tv_container higher than the z-index for tv-video2